# Determining whether a circular number is nearly equal to another

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working with radians within a range of [-PI, PI]. Values outside that range are converted to valid values with the following function

```
double Radian::convert(double input) {
    if (input > RAD_UPPER_BOUND) return RAD_LOWER_BOUND + fmod(input, RAD_UPPER_BOUND);
    if (input < RAD_LOWER_BOUND) return RAD_UPPER_BOUND + fmod(input, RAD_UPPER_BOUND);
                                 return input;
}
```

My question is: how can I implement logic to check whether radian A is within x in either direction of radian B. I want to specifiy x when calling the function.

Assuming A = 3.0; B = -2.5; x = 1; the function should return true because A and B are less than x apart.

I'm assuming that there is a standard way of handling this type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main trick here is to realize that the values can't be more than half the total span away from each other.

```
bool isWithinDistance(double a,double b,double within_distance)
{
    assert(a >= RAD_LOWER_BOUND);
    assert(a <= RAD_UPPER_BOUND);
    assert(b >= RAD_LOWER_BOUND);
    assert(b <= RAD_UPPER_BOUND);
    assert(within_distance >= 0);

    double span = RADIAN_UPPER_BOUND-RADIAN_LOWER_BOUND;
    double distance = fabs(a-b);

    if (distance > span/2) {
        distance = span-distance;
    }

    return distance<within_distance;
}
```

In your example:

```
a = 3.0; 
b = -2.5; 
within_distance = 1;
span = 2*PI;
distance = fabs(a-b) = 5.5;
distance > PI, so
    distance = 2*PI - 5.5 ~= 0.7832;
result = (distance < 1) = true;
```

Comment: span will be 2 * PI in my case even if the actual range is from -PI to PI (PI - (-PI) = 2 * PI)

Comment: @A.B.: Right, so your values can't be more than PI away from each other.